# How to remove all the element in the slice with reflect package in Golang?

Tags: pointers, go, reflection, slice

I'm trying to create a function that can reset a passed slice like this:

```
func resetSlice(slice interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    s := v.Type().Elem() 
    // QUESTION: How to reset the slice here?
}

usernames := []string{"Hello", "World"}
resetSlice(&usernames)

fmt.Println(usernames) // OUTPUT  : [Hello World]
                       // EXPECTED: []
```

But I have no idea about how to reset a pointer slice. Maybe create a new slice which has the same type as the pointer slice with

```
reflect.New(v.Type().Elem())
```

then replace the the pointer slice? But how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `reflect.MakeSlice` instead.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func resetSlice(slice interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    v.Elem().Set(reflect.MakeSlice(v.Type().Elem(), 0, v.Elem().Cap()))
}


func main() {
    a := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz"}  
    resetSlice(&a)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/JNWE0hCsQp